# object has no attribute 'add' on python's protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I want to test the nested message on protobuf's API on python.

My proto `ndemo.proto` file was:

```
package ndemotest;

message BaseRequest
{
    required bytes Key = 1;
}

message ContRequest
{
    required BaseRequest baseRequest = 1;
    optional string Url = 2;
}
```

My python `ndemo.py` code was:

```
import binascii
import ndemo_pb2


contReq = ndemo_pb2.ContRequest()
contReq.Url="www.google.com"

base_request = contReq.baseRequest.add()
base_request.Key="12345"


packed_data = contReq.SerializeToString()

print 'sending "%s"' % binascii.hexlify(packed_data)
```

When I ran my script as `python ndemo.py`, there was an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ndemo.py", line 8, in
>   
>       base_request = contReq.baseRequest.add() AttributeError: 'BaseRequest' object has no attribute 'add'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have `add()` for a `repeated` field, that's the point of it.

In your case, as `baseRequest` is `required`, you should simply assign the value directly to the field within `BaseRequest`, like:

```
contReq = ndemo_pb2.ContRequest()
contReq.baseRequest.key = "12345"
```